# hide tabBar on screens using drawer + tabs + stack

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I want to hide the tab bar in some screens, to be more exact in the screens after the main screen of each tab.

I am using reac navigation 5
React native with hooks

I have the following layout, I am using drawer, tabs, and stack.

[image: distribution react navigation]

I want the tab bar to be displayed normally when the user stops at the shopping cart tab, but when the user clicks a button that takes him to another screen of the shopping cart stack, I want the tab bar to no longer be visible .

That is, only in the main screens of the tabs, the tab bar is present, in the other screens, it should not.

This behavior is satisfactory with Home, but not in the other tabs.

I really appreciate any help, I receive comments, suggestions, and anything to make this navigation distribution much better.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in my app in the following way:

```
  import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

  { ... }

  // Hide parent tab bar on focus
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      // Do something when the screen is focused
      const parent = dangerouslyGetParent();
      if (parent) {
        parent.setOptions({
          tabBarVisible: false,
        });
      }

      return () => {

      };
    }, [dangerouslyGetParent]),
  );
```

Beware though.  To make this really work when using `navigation.pop()` or navigating back to a previous screen you will need to add this same code to the components you want to ensure do show the tab bar as this modifies the navigator configuration itself.  So you would just do the same in screens that get navigated to from the disabled tab bar screen with the above code sub `tabBarVisible: true`

I haven't really found a better way from researching when I was digging.  Would love for other solutions that are more elegant but this at least will get you started and functionality working.